# Aggregate numpy array dynamically (aggregation function is parameterized)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Aggregate a set of values with a parameterized aggregation function.

I have a numpy array of numeric values, and an aggregation function which is a parameter (options are sum, count, avg, max, min, etc.). How can I apply this aggregation function dynamically in the code ?

```
combined_vals_list = [1,2,3]
vals_df = pd.DataFrame({'values': combined_vals_list , 'group': [1]*len(combined_vals_list)})
                    agg_col_query_value = 
vals_df.groupby('group').aggregate(agg).iloc[0,0]
```

the expected result is 6 and my code returns 6 , but this way of using pandas seem cumbersome.
Any better and more efficient simpler way ?

Comment: You can do something like a `dict` of strings to functions, but in Pandas you can also just write it like `pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).aggregate('sum')`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that pandas apparently the best way to achieve dynamic parameterized aggregation
pd.Series([1, 2, 3]).aggregate('sum') per jdehesa comment